# extract value of href a tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<tr class="field_20 field_facebook">
<td class="label">Facebook</td>
<td class="data"><p><a href="http://facebook.com/facebook">Test</a></p>
</td></tr>
<img id="fb" src="fb.png">
```

Hello, so this is what I have and I want to select using jquery the value `http://facebook.com/facebook` and open the link.
this is what I have so far:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#fb").click(function() {
  var fb = jQuery(".field_20 field_facebook").find("a").attr("href");
window.open(fb);

}); //click function ends
}); // document ready ends
</script>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Does what you've tried work? If not, what goes wrong? Are there any errors?

Comment: works for me! http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/9dy2k/

Comment: The only problem I see is the way you're selecting the `<a>`. Classes should be chained using a `.` to concatenate. Like this: `jQuery(".field_20.field_facebook a").attr("href")`.

Comment: no errors it open a blank window . I am trying to select the first href value that comes right after this : <tr class="field_20 field_facebook">

Comment: yeah it works after I remove the second class I forgot a . that was dumb. thank you~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.field_20.field_facebook` (no space, but a period).

The `class` attribute allows you to define multiple classes on the same element with a space.  This is distinct from jQuery (and CSS) selectors where the space is a descendant selector.  That is, `.field_20 field_facebook` tries to select a `<field_facebook>` element that is a descendant of an element with the `.field_20` class.  Using `.field_20 .field_facebook` would not work either because the descendant selector is still there.  Omitting the space is proper syntax for selecting via multiple classes on the same element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#fb").click(function() {
        var fb = $('td.data a').attr('href');
        alert(fb);
        window.open(fb);
    }); //click function ends

}); //END $(document).ready()
```

Comment: I have other td.data a ... thats why I specified the : field_20 field_facebook, that needs to be used to target that specific TR

Answer (score 1):

Your selector line can be simplified to:

```
var fb = jQuery(".field_20.field_facebook a").attr("href");
```

Just like in CSS, you can select the `a` which is a child of an element with class `.field_20.field_facebook`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr class="field_20 field_facebook">
```

The classes are available on the same element.

So there should be no space between the 2 classes when used in the selector.

```
jQuery(".field_20.field_facebook")
```

Use the line below to access the `facebook` link

```
jQuery(".field_20.field_facebook a").attr("href");
```

Comment: and to get the attr of the link that is inside a TD inside the TR ?

Comment: `jQuery(".field_20.field_facebook a").attr("href");` should do